# One element, multiple events

Tags: javascript, html, function

In jQuery you can easily do it like this:

```
$("#foo").focus(function () {
    // Do this.
}).blur(function () {
    // Do that.
});
```

Can we do something similar in pure JavaScript so we don't have to repeat `#foo` in two separate functions?

Comment: jQuery is a regular javascript. hypothetically you answered your own question.

Comment: This is called method chainning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable; really!

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

foo.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    // Do this.
});

foo.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    // Do that.
});
```

Or a helper, if you prefer:

```
function on(eventSource, listeners) {
    for (var k in listeners) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(listeners, k)) {
            eventSource.addEventListener(k, listeners[k]);
        }
    }
}

on(foo, {
    focus: function () {
        // Do this.
    },
    blur: function () {
        // Do that.
    }
});
```

Or a chaining helper:

```
function chainOnly(obj) {
    var wrapper = {};

    function createChainWrapper(func) {
        return function wrapped() {
            func.apply(obj, arguments);
            return wrapper;
        };
    }

    for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'function') {
            wrapper[k] = createChainWrapper(obj[k]);
        }
    }

    return wrapper;
}

chainOnly(foo)
    .addEventListener('focus', function () { /* … */ })
    .addEventListener('blur',  function () { /* … */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in your solution you have used `foo` twice in two separate functions.

Comment: @Hermes: That’s not really a bad thing.

Comment: Just thought it can help shorten the code. And using a helper makes things too complicated for me.

Comment: I think he would want the `call()` `this` argument to be `eventSource` instead of `listeners`

Comment: @AlexW: It’ll still be `eventSource`. JavaScript doesn’t bind functions to objects like Python.

Comment: @false—I think the *chainOnly* method will be very inefficient, *wrapper* will get a property for every enumerable method on the DOM element, which might be quite a lot (69 for a div) that is a function wrapping the same–named DOM property. This is very similar to the paradigm used by Prototype.js and since abandoned.

Comment: @false: "_That’s not really a bad thing._" It seems that I should listen to this advice. Other methods are longer and more complicated than simply using two separate functions for `#foo`.